# What happened to the journal club?

Tags: discussion, participation, journal-club

There were a series of seven chat session called the CV journal club but no more after that. There still seemed to be plenty of interested people at the seventh based on the post for that session but after that it apparently stopped dead. Does anyone remember why?

Comment: Don't know the answer, but nowadays, it seems a lot of work, considering CV has grown, so as the required maintenance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was around when the journal clubs took place, so here is my take.

The journal club (and the blog) were events outside the usual Q/A that a few involved community members took time to initiate. Neither built up much outside participation, so when those few motivated individuals stopped doing them, they effectively died.

There was no negative push-back from the community, but to be viable they needed to have (many) more people participate and to help organize. So I chalk them up to a failed experiment.

A long time ago, the community was more worried about attracting outside individuals - and these were things we thought might help to advertise CV. That isn't so much a problem now - we need to worry more about answering the tons of questions we have.

So in short, there wasn't anything wrong with them, but they never really served any vital function to the community either.